# Can not access remote dimension (time) in cascaded WMS

Tags: geoserver, wms, getcapabilities

I try to add weather radar (WMS) into Stores, here is steps:

1. select  WMS link from new Stores
2. enter weather radar URL: https://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities&layer=RADAR_1KM_RSNO
3. After saving, and publish weather radar layer; in the Dimensions tab, I cannot find time or other  attribute list.

But I can find following when open radar url in the browser like :

`<Dimension name="time" units="ISO8601" default="2022-02-11T00:30:00Z" nearestValue="0">2022-02-10T21:30:00Z/2022-02-11T00:30:00Z/PT10M</Dimension>`

How do I get it working?

Comment: I'm looking to do something similar with time from a gov't resource.  This explains that "Extra request parameters (time, elevation, cql_filter, etc.) cannot be used."  I'll post the source documentation when I find it. 
 http://mapotecaweb.integracionsocial.gov.co:8081/opengeo-docs/geoserver/data/cascaded/wms.html

Answer (score 2):

GeoServer can use time dimension on local resources, either raster or vector data. However, it cannot do the same on cascaded WMSs, the code to do that is simply missing. The reason is simple, nobody sponsored such development, up until now (funny enough, there is some support for WMTS instead).

So, someone has to write the code, or to sponsor a developer to do it on their behalf. Here is a guide for you:
https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-fixes,-improvements-and-new-features-in-GeoServer